# How to overwrite icon/image path with diazo

Tags: plone, diazo

how can i overwrite images/icons from plone with theme-specific icons from my theme?

i want to turn

```
<img width="16" height="16" alt="Image" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/plone/image.png">
```

into

```
<img width="16" height="16" alt="Image" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/plone/++theme++mytheme/image.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to make this particular change is to simply set `++theme++mytheme/image.png` as the icon for the Image type in portal_types either through the web or with a generic setup profile.

If you must make the change in diazo, then you could use:

```
<replace css:content="img[src$=/image.png]"><img width="16" height="16" alt="Image" src="image.png" /></replace>
```

Comment: i get an "AssertionError: Unexpected symbol: '/' at 9" with that expression

Comment: Try quoting it: ``img[src$='/image.png']``